# Quickblox: Is it possible to delete all custom objects created by the user

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

Is it possible to delete all custom objects of specific class for the current user with one API call?

The call could be something like this:

```
[QBCustomObjects deleteObjectsForClassName:@"ClassName" delegate:self];
```

This would be useful when the user wants to delete his/her account or otherwise would like to remove all entries he has created for the specific class.

In addition, this would be beneficial in case the application has, for any reason, lost the class IDs needed in deleting individual objects. This would then remove the additional step to get all class ids first before starting to remove them individually.

Please let me know if this is possible and I have missed something.. And any tips on how to do this in most efficient way in terms of bandwidth & API usage are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

(I am using Quickblox iOS SDK: version with latest git commit: Wed Nov 27 18:52:20 2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete all objects for **specific class** in 3 steps:

1) Retrieve all objects by QBCustomObjects class:

```
objectsWithClassName:extendedRequest:delegate:
```

2) Create array, going through all items in a loop and collect their item ID.

3) Perform deleting by QBCustomObjects class (and pass array of IDs)

```
deleteObjectsWithIDs:className:delegate:
```

(For more details how to use this methods, please check this http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Classes/QBCustomObjects.html)

**PS**: I don't know, may be this feature appear in SDK later.

Comment: It's true solution.
Actually only owner of the record can delete his record. Other users can't do it. That's why QuickBlox doesn't provide [QBCustomObjects deleteObjectsForClassName:@"ClassName" delegate:self]; method now.

Comment: Thanks @frankWhite for your response! This is the process I do at the moment in case I have to clean up all the items plus in addition to me storing all class IDs separately for the user for multiple classes. I was just wondering if it can be made easier as this is inefficient (many API calls back and forth, especially when using paging for big number of items) and complex way to do simple database operation.

Comment: Thanks @Igor for the comment. Wouldn't it be still useful to provide operation to simply delete all records of the owner for specific class? I agree that it does not have to provide methods to delete records of other users.

Comment: Yes, QuickBlox team thinks about it. Like delete with filters.

Comment: Nice to hear! This feature would, by-the-way, differentiate you positively against other similar services, such as Parse (last time I checked, they did not provide such method either.. I might be wrong thought).

Comment: Dear @IgorKhomenko, have you had any thought in re: to delete with filters functionality with rest of QB team? This would be fantastic feature for my upcoming application -- some of the users in the database may have 2-4k upto 5000 custom objects and I allow them to do clean up/delete their data. This would take about 0.1sec processing time per item and currently when I delete them all individually in addition to network communication delays the total time would be around 0.2sec per item summing up to 1000secs (15-17 minutes). I am currently checking whether I can use less objects per user.